# Divison without division operator

Tags: python

I was trying to solve this question from leetcode:

> Given two integers dividend and divisor, divide two integers without
> using multiplication, division, and mod operator. The integer division
> should truncate toward zero

My solution:

```
def divide(dividend, divisor):
    pseudo_count = 0 # pseudo-count
    flag = False # True if divisor or dividend is negative
    if dividend < 0:
        dividend = -dividend
        flag = True
    if divisor < 0:
        divisor = -divisor
        flag = True

    for i in range (0, dividend):
        pseudo_count += divisor
        if pseudo_count > dividend:
            if flag:
                return -i
            else:
                return i

    return -1
```

But `divide(-10, -3)` returns -3.

Can anyone spot the mistake here?

Comment: Why set flag=True when both numbers have the same sign?

Comment: Cheating answer: `int.__floordiv__(dividend, divisor)`

Comment: At first, I solved one of them being negative, then implemented flag for the both @jarmod

Comment: That's actually cool @0x5453

Comment: Try to think about the logic carefully. "At first, I solved one of them being negative, then implemented flag for the both" If both are negative, what should the value of `flag` be? Why? Now, how can you modify the code to address that?

Comment: make an algorithm which does not care about the sign of the numbers, `abs` to make the positive. Then check the sign and correct the final result

Comment: Yes, I can always solve that as you said. But I'm curious specifically what is wrong with my algorithm @cards

Comment: Probably 'false' because the flag indicates if divisor and dividend have the same sign @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 2):

A minor change fixes your code.

- Initialize the flag to False (no negative)
- We flip the flag each time there is a negative
- One negative sets the flag to True (one flip)
- Two negatives sets the flag to False (two flips)

**Code**

```
def divide(dividend, divisor):
    pseudo_count = 0 # pseudo-count
    flag = False                # Initialize flag (no negatives)
    if dividend < 0:
        dividend = -dividend
        flag = not flag         # flip flag: 
                                # changes True to False and False to True
    if divisor < 0:
        divisor = -divisor
        flag = not flag         # flip flag:
                                # changes True to False and False to True

    # Note: two flips above solve the both negative issue
    for i in range (0, dividend):
        pseudo_count += divisor
        if pseudo_count > dividend:
            if flag:
                return -i
            else:
                return i

    return -1

divide(-10, -3)
# Output: 3
```

Comment: Can you explain the not flag part for a little bit?

Comment: @goku - does the updated answer adequately the mod to your code?

Comment: Yes. So it was all about flags being ambigous. Nice solution, thanks a lot